# Deleting a row in a DataRow [] C #

Tags: c#, asp.net, datarow

I make a call to BD and he brings me an info which I order as follows:

```
Backlog.GetDocAllUsersDataTable data = service.GetDocAllUsersDataTable(string.Empty)
DataRow[] rows = data.Select().OrderBy(x => x["UserName"]).ToArray;
```

In my array 'rows' I have the BD items sorted but after I make a condition to eliminate some items, I tried with:

```
rows[0].Delete();
data.AcceptChanges();
```

But what it does is format all the fields of position 0 but it does not delete it, that is to say that if 26 records arrive I still have the same 26 and I need 25 left. Thanks ...

Comment: ````Try data.Rows[0].Delete()````  -- This is just a guess, but it seems like you are creating an Array and deleting from that Array, but the original ```data``` object has not be touched.

Comment: Try List<DataRow> instead of an array.   The Array has less features than list.  Then use Remove instead of Delete.

Answer (score 1):

The `ToArray` call copies the data table contents into a *separate* array.  So `rows[0].Delete()` does nothing to the original `data`.

Try this instead:

```
Backlog.GetDocAllUsersDataTable data = service.GetDocAllUsersDataTable(string.Empty)
data.OrderBy(x => x["UserName"]).First().Delete();
data.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but the same error continues to appear, I get 26 BD records and when I make your contribution, what it does is erase all the info for that position, but it does not completely eliminate it. 25 items should remain

Comment: Do you need to delete 26 items? How do you identify these 26 items?
`data.Where(x => /* select condition */ ).Delete();`